# How do I run an Excel macro for when a cell is changed but the data has not been entered yet?

Tags: excel, input, paste, vba

Here's the problem: I have a laser scanner that reads barcodes and regurgitates a value upon a successful reading.  When this happens, the serial number (a ~20-digit number) is pasted into the active cell.  *Pasted*, but not *entered*.  I want to know if there's any way to include in the private sub some sort of "If data pasted" statement.

The second purpose of the code is to timestamp each entry in the column to the right, like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then        
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = Now()
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Activate
    End If

End Sub
```

Data won't be inputted rapidly, so the relative cell references shouldn't be a problem.
If you see anything else that could be improved, please don't hesitate to mention it!

EDIT: Because some have brought it up, this is not a "simple" paste; the data is placed into the formula bar, but it is not entered.

EDIT 2: Here is another person with my [same problem.](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/8817-excel-macro-will-press-enter-after-data-entered.html)

Comment: You don't need to activate a cell before writing to it. The 3 lines within the `If-EndIf` can be written as  `Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now`

Comment: Also you dont need a `"If data pasted" statement.` the above `Worksheet_Change` event will fire when u paste data in a cell as well.

Comment: @SiddharthRout The problem is that when the data is inputted, the data acts as if it is being placed into the Formula bar without hitting "Enter", so it's not a "true" paste.

Comment: what do u exactly want to achieve?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I want my macro to run every time I scan a barcode (every time data is pasted into the Formula bar of Excel).  At the very least, I'll need some way to trigger an "Enter" keystroke (instead of just leaving it unsubmitted in the formula bar).  I know this could be achieved by continuous looping, but I'd rather not do that.  I'm not certain that this is possible, but I thought I would ask.

Comment: @SiddharthRout This is essentially my question:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/8817-excel-macro-will-press-enter-after-data-entered.html

Comment: No offense. Why use excel to capture the bar-codes?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I want to use a spreadsheet as a permanent record of the date and time a uniquely identified component is scanned, for purposes of traceability.  (Customization on the scanner is very limited.)  If you can think of any better way, I'd appreciate it, but it would probably be beneficial if it were Excel-compatible.

Comment: The reason I asked is - Instead of Excel cells, use a form with a textbox to capture the barcode, use the textbox events (such as `Change` event, see if it is exact length assuming all barcodes are X characters), using that put the data into the cells with the time stamp.

Comment: @shahkalpesh I was about to try that next, but it actually turns out that there *was* a customizable setting to fix my problem :X  Thank you for your time, and if ever the situation should arise in the future, I'll consider your solution!

Comment: @SiddharthRout I figured out how to tweak the scanner settings, so the problem got solved, after all!  Thank you so much for all your valuable input, and I'm sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @user2447846: Can you put the solution in the answer below, specifically the setting that helped you achieve what you wanted? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I was out for dinner. But I see your problem is solved :) I agree with @shahkalpesh. Post a the solution that you arrived at. That would help future visitors as well...

Comment: The solution wasn't on Excel's side; I had to leave open the (DataMan) scanner software so the output strings would be properly formatted.  Otherwise, I ran into the aforementioned problem.

Answer (score 0):

The barcode reader is just a replacement of the keyboard that types in alphanumerics read from the barcode. The problem is that it does not type the enter key. You may want to check if there is a way to activate this capability in the barcode reader. Example here: https://docs.symbol.com/KanisaPlatform/Publishing/444/ADC-01244_f.SAL_Public.html

There does not exist an event exposed by Excel to VBA to pickup keystrokes and eventually changes in the formula bar.

According to this source: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/686972-key-press-event-in-he-formula-bar.html, you cannot capture the keypress event of character typed in the formula bar. The same source describes a possible way to do it involving hacking your way into listening to events getting to the formula bar window via Win32 API. Nothing exciting in there.